# Unable to understand the extact meaning of 'OR' in a sentance?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, indian-english

I'm applying for a home loan and there is an sentence which is quite confusing for me. Please help me to solve this confusion. Here is the sentence -

> As per the same, the maximum amount of loan towards the cost of land can be allowed up to 50% of the project cost or the eligible limit, whichever is lower, and the balance amount of limit will be available towards construction of house.

My doubt is that what does - "50% of the project cost or the eligible limit" mean ?

For eg. if project cost is 100 and my eligibility is 60 then am I eligible for 50 or 30 ?

Comment: I would say that common sense says you get half the money for land and half for construction of the house, and the total amount you get is the lower of the project cost or eligible limit. However, this is more a question of interpreting the terms of a loan agreement than of pure English, and I think you should seek clarity from the load provider or broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the English language doesn't tell you. You have to use common sense to tell which way it is meant.

Consider:

"I need a clean sheet or blanket."

Does the blanket need to be clean? You can't tell. Probably -- why would someone want a dirty blanket when the sheet needs to be clean? But the grammar doesn't tell you.

"I need a charged electric bike or a non-electric bike."

Grammar doesn't tell you whether the non-electric bike also needs to be charged, but common sense does.

This is entirely possible:

"As per the same, the maximum amount of loan towards the cost of land can be allowed up to 50% of (**the project cost**) or (**the eligible limit**), whichever is lower, and the balance amount of limit will be available towards construction of house."

But English grammar allows this interpretation too:

"As per the same, the maximum amount of loan towards the cost of land can be allowed up to of (**50% of the project cost**) or (**the eligible limit**), whichever is lower, and the balance amount of limit will be available towards construction of house."

You simply cannot tell from rules of English grammar and have to know whether or not it makes sense to leave nothing left over for construction.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your views. You are right, it's more of a contextual answer instead of looking at English grammer. I had contacted the mortgage officer and he clarified that it's the - "50% of the project cost not the 50% of the eligibility limit "

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase is "whichever is lower".

So if "50% of the project cost" is 50  and the eligible limit is 60 the lower value is "50" because 50 is lower than 60.

It seems you suppose that "50%" should be applied to the "eligible limit", to give a lower value of "30".  This is an unlikely interpretation  (because a limit is understood to be a limit and not 200% of a limit)  Grammatically it is ambiguous. A comma could be inserted before "or" to reduce the ambiguity.

The "plain meaning" is that 50 is lower than 60, so 50 is the maximum amount.  It is possible that the rest of the document suggests a different interpretation.

If your job depends on the unambiguous interpretation of this clause, then your only option is to clarify with the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

It is comparing two numbers.  The first is most likely

> 50% of the project cost

and the second is most likely

> the eligible limit

So, the answer to your question above would be 50.

If they meant 50% to modify either of the two numbers, it would be written like this:

> 50% of the lesser of the project cost and the eligible limit

But since it is reasonably ambiguous, if you have any doubts, please do ask your lender for clarification!

Comment: I'm puzzled why this was downvoted. It's a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree. Upvoted.